# Can I add a .NET 4.5.1 project as a reference to a DNX project?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

I have a class library using dotNet 4.5.1 and would like to add it as a reference to a DNX project.  I get the following error:

> A reference to 'yClassLibrary' could not be added.

My DNX project only supports .NET 4.5.1 using this line in project.json:

```
"frameworks": {
   "net451": { }
}
```

Comment: Your title says "DBX" but your question says "DNX". Is one of those a typo?

Comment: Have you looked at `dnu wrap`?